# Where are definitions or references for the IORegistry Values?

Tags: macos, mac

If you use ioreg or the ioregistryexplorer.app there are values for a ton of data struvtures. I have yet to find a reference on what any of these values mean. For instance under the AppleACPIPPlatformExpert I want to know what the "Wake Reason" value means. Has anyone ever seen documentation for any of this stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the Wake Reason is filled with the ID of what device woke the computer up from sleep.

As for documentation, there is some on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/index.html) but it's decidedly aimed towards developers using I/O Kit.

Comment: thank you but I've been all over the developer site and have not found any reference to any of these values. Perhaps you could tell me where you found that the wake reason is the ID of the device that cause the wake from sleep?

Answer (score 0):

The keys and values are particular to various drivers. Some of those drivers are [open source](http://opensource.apple.com/), and you can suss out how they interpret various keys and their values. The drivers that are not open source are unlikely to have any public documentation of their keys and values. The IO registry is primarily of interest to kernel extension developers, and even their interest is likely to be localized to a particular family of drivers, such as USB or Firewire.